# Creating folder with user input : Android

Tags: android

```
jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()
        {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
         {
            //int imageNum = 0;

            String Name = PatientInfo.getText().toString();

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + Name);
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
            File output = new File(imagesFolder, s.toString() + ".jpg");
          //  String fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
         //   File output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
       /*     while (output.exists()){
                imageNum++;
                fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(imageNum) + ".jpg";
                output = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
            }*/
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);
                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

                Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                        "Image saved: ", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
    };
```

This is a code example. I am trying to create folder with a userinput when it is entered. Each time i need to create new folders on entering new username. But in this there is something missing.Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: i need to create a folder when i enter a username . here no folder is created while i enter a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + Name);
```

withFile

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  Name);
```

Please be sure to have also the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION` in the manifest, and that `Name` is not null

Comment: Both should have the same result as per the documentation. Can you elaborate why the latter works, but the first one (apparently) not?

Comment: he missed the file separator concatenating names. He is trying to create a directory inside /mnt with name sdcardname and he has not the permission to do so @JeffreyKlardie

Comment: Nicely spotted. Just checked the Android source, and eventually the constructors do the same thing.

Comment: I never checked it but I guess so. Also, if you look at the documentation, in the constructor that takes two parameter, the first is a File and they called the parameter dir.. so imo simply reading the documentation you can understand that is more safe to use that one in this case that the one with only a parameter. But, of course, it is only matter of taste.

Comment: yuppp...its working..thanks...but when i enter second username, the activity crashes out.i think i should do smthing with onDestroy ...am i right?

Comment: I do not think it is related to this issue. You should accept this answer and try to figure it out by yourself. You are not able feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: i figured it out...Just stop the activity in onDestroy()